# Circe: Decode Each Member of Array to Case Class

Tags: scala, circe

I'm learning Circe and need help navigating json hierarchies.

Given a json defined as follows:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser._

val jStr = """
{
    "a1": ["c1", "c2"],
    "a2": [{"d1": "abc", "d2": "efg"}, {"d1": "hij", "d2": "klm"}]
}
"""


val j = parse(jStr).getOrElse(Json.Null)

val ja = j.hcursor.downField("a2").as[Json].getOrElse("").toString

ja
```

`ja` is now: `[ { "d1" : "abc", "d2" : "efg" }, { "d1" : "hij", "d2" : "klm" } ]`

I can now do the following to this list:

```
case class Song(id: String, title: String)

implicit val songDecoder: Decoder[Song] = (c: HCursor ) => for {
    id <- c.downField("d1").as[String]
    title <- c.downField("d2").as[String]
} yield Song(id,title)

 io.circe.parser.decode[List[Song]](ja).getOrElse("")
```

Which returns what I want:  `List(Song(abc,efg), Song(hij,klm))`

My questions are as follows:

1. How do I add item a1.c1 from the original json (`j`) to each item retrieved from the array? I want to add it to `Song` modified as follows: `case class Song(id: String, title: String, artist: String)`
2. It seems wrong to turn the json object back into a String for the iterative step of retrieving `id` and `title`. Is there a way to do this without turning json into String?

Comment: Any particular reason to write codecs by hand rather than generating them?

Comment: I "borrowed" this approach from a post on Stack Overflow. If you have a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest [`circe-generic`](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/semiauto-derivation.html) or [`circe-generic-extra`](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html) - define case classes that match the JSON schema, derive the codecs, and if you want some other format call `.map` on `Decoder`/`.contramap` on `Encoder` to map case classes for JSON to case classes you want to work with.